# Linux Telnet vt100 Return key sends ^M

Tags: linux, tcl, telnet, expect, enter

I'm writing Telnet automation scripts with TCL and Expect in Linux Debian.
Pressing Return in a Telnet session or within a *.tcl script (`send "command\r"`) and even `send "command\n"` causes the line being send with *^M* (Ctrl+M) at the end. Off course, the remote host treats those commands as illegal. Tried to `telnet` `set crlf` prior to the opening of the connection and `mode line` while connected, but this has no effect.
Using Puttys GUI, I've enabled [this](http://en.helpdoc-online.com/putty_0.6/source/config-telnetnl.html) option to send a new line by pressing Return instead of *^M*. Works fine. How do I configure this option for `telnet` ?

Help would be much appreciated!

**Edit:**

`stty -a`

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;      rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon     -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

`stty` (with `stty icrnl` enabled)

```
speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel
```

Comment: Same issue with empty-expect.

Comment: Err, `\r` *is* Ctrl-M.

Comment: @EJP: Yeah, for sure: `\r` is Ctrl-M and `\n` is Ctrl-J. But I don't want to send those Chars to the remote host, cause they are decoded as plain text, not as terminal codes.

Answer (score 1):

The command "stty" might be able to change your end-of-line settings.

First, see what you have currently set:

```
stty -a
```

Then try one of the options available.

```
stty ocrnl
```

This should translate a carriage return to a new-line.

You can undo this setting with a minus sign:

```
stty -ocrnl
```

If that doesn't work take a look at onlret or maybe onlcr.

It's difficult to test this without having your exact environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried `stty ocrnl` `onlret` and `onlcr`, sadly it has no effect to the return command within a `telnet` session. According to man, `ocrnl` seems to be what I want. My environments: Raspian Wheezy and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Running `stty` returns: `eol = M-^?`, same for eol2. `stty eol CHAR` requires a char, but I don't want to send a eol CHAR to the remote host at all.

Comment: Maybe I had my in's and out's wrong. Please try "stty icrnl". This definitely changes the terminal behavior on my Mac. Perhaps you could post the output of "stty -a". You can check your work with "cat >ttytest" and terminate with a control-D then print what you have with "hexdump -C ttytest" to see what actual codes are being generated.

Comment: `stty icrnl` works fine for `cat >ttytest`, return key produces a new line without _^M_. Using `stty -icrnl` and `cat >ttytest`, the return key produces an _^M_. But this has absolutely no effect to the behaviour of `telnet`.

Comment: Now that you have a clear picture of what character codes are being fed into telnet it's time to look at what terminal is being emulated. Probably vt100. Launch telnet and enter command "environ list". Try a switch to ansi. In telnet issue command "environ define TERM ansi".  I'm about to run out of ideas.

Comment: Sadly, the TERM variable doesn't work at all for Emulation: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-10.html#ss10.2 But you're right, I've to use ANSI Emulation. That's what I do under OS Windows with Hyperterminal. I can't believe, that ANSI emulation is'nt possible with Linux `telnet`. I'm at my wit's end. ):