# Tcl Expect: variable send response to complex authentification prompt

Tags: regex, authentication, tcl, expect, telnet

This is an excerpt of the relevant parts from a TCL script known to be working with a Telnet server.

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}
package require Expect
#USER
set user xyz
set secret 12345678
set smr AB1CDE-11
set host foo.bar
#TELNET START
spawn telnet $host
expect "\[Login :\]"
send "$user\r";
expect "=>"
#RMS
send "c $smr gate\r";
expect "$smr >"
send "PW $secret\r"
expect "\[>\]"
```

The login procedure has changed a couple of days ago. Response with `send "PW $secret\r"` is not possible anymore. After the `$smr >` response, any command could be send to initiate login, e.g. `send "login\r"`. The telnet responds with `Login [517]:`. The numbers inside the [] are corresponding to the position in `$secret`. A full `$secrect` response does not succeed anymore. The server expects a response which contains all three characters plus three additional characters.

For some reasons, I want the position of the characters from `$secret` to be at a random position among three random characters (possible chars in RegEx terms: `[A-Z0-9.!@#$%^&*()_]`). The length of `$secret` is variable. So I couldn't set a variable for each character to respond with them to a RegEx matchresult.

The right RegExp to capture the position of the characters would be `LOGIN \[(\d)(\d)(\d)]:`, right? I've got as far as the following (output is captured in a text file for statistical post-processing as I'm evaluating the randomness of the login procedure).

```
send "login\r"    
set input [open output_$user.txt a]
set output $expect_out(buffer)
puts $input $output
close $input
expect "LOGIN"
#Check LOGIN prompt
set file [read [open "output_$user.txt" r]]
if [
regexp -nocase {LOGIN \[(\d)(\d)(\d)]:} 
] then {
send "RESPONSE\r";
}
```

How I can I solve this issue with TCL? Thanks!

**Ammendment:** 
After connecting to the Telnet Server with `send "c $smr gate\r";`

```
XYZ SMC via AB1CDE-11 >
```

is being replied, which is being expected by `expect "$smr >"`. Until here, everything works fine.
To the following `send "login\r"`, the Telnet server replies with two lines:

```
Login [517]:
XYZ SMC via AB1CDE-11 >
```

The matching RegEx would be `Login \[(\d)(\d)(\d)\]:\n.*>`.
I've tried different expect RegEx syntaxes:
donal-fellows `expect -re {Login \[(\d)(\d)(\d)\]:}` Crash of TCL
`expect -re -n {Login \[(\d)(\d)(\d)\]:\n.*>}` Crash of TCL
`expect {-re -n "Login \[(\d)(\d)(\d)\]:"}` exit
Only something without regular expression (`-re`) like `expect "$smr >"` or `expect "LOGIN"` works, and TCL does'nt exit.
TCL appcompat (PATH of FOLDER has been anonymized):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<DATABASE>
<EXE NAME="tclsh.exe" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_PRIVACY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="base-tcl8.6-thread-win32-ix86.dll" SIZE="2023820" CHECKSUM="0xFCEB4A60" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.4" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Tcl DLL" COMPANY_NAME="ActiveState Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Tcl 8.6 for Windows" FILE_VERSION="8.6.4" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="tcl86.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2001 by ActiveState Corporation, et al" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1693A0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 23:56:02" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 23:56:02" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="base-tcl8.6-thread-win32-ix86.exe" SIZE="2445716" CHECKSUM="0x2B1899DD" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.4" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Tclsh Application" COMPANY_NAME="ActiveState Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Tcl 8.6 for Windows" FILE_VERSION="8.6.4" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="tclsh86s.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2000 by ActiveState Corporation, et al" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 23:41:45" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 23:41:45" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="base-tk8.6-thread-win32-ix86.exe" SIZE="3713462" CHECKSUM="0xB94B598D" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.4" FILE_DESCRIPTION="ActiveState Basekit" COMPANY_NAME="ActiveState Software Inc." PRODUCT_NAME="TDK Basekit 8.6 for Windows" FILE_VERSION="8.6.4" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="basekit.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2009 by ActiveState Software Inc." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 23:46:01" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 23:46:01" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="tcl86.dll" SIZE="1228800" CHECKSUM="0x3BC33EBF" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.4" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Tcl DLL" COMPANY_NAME="ActiveState Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Tcl 8.6 for Windows" FILE_VERSION="8.6.4" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="tcl86.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2001 by ActiveState Corporation, et al" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x12F33A" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 22:59:49" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 22:59:49" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="tclsh.exe" SIZE="393216" CHECKSUM="0x9050007E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.4" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Tclsh Application" COMPANY_NAME="ActiveState Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Tcl 8.6 for Windows" FILE_VERSION="8.6.4" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="tclsh86.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2000 by ActiveState Corporation, et al" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 22:59:57" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 22:59:57" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="tclsh86.exe" SIZE="393216" CHECKSUM="0x9050007E" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.4" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Tclsh Application" COMPANY_NAME="ActiveState Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Tcl 8.6 for Windows" FILE_VERSION="8.6.4" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="tclsh86.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2000 by ActiveState Corporation, et al" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 22:59:57" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 22:59:57" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="teacup.exe" SIZE="3259545" CHECKSUM="0xFDE41297" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.5.2.18" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.5.2.18" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.5.18" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Tclsh Application" COMPANY_NAME="ActiveState Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Tcl 8.5 for Windows" FILE_VERSION="8.5.18" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="tclsh85s.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2000 by ActiveState Corporation, et al" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.5.2.18" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.5.2.18" LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 04:34:28" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 04:34:28" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="tk86.dll" SIZE="1433600" CHECKSUM="0x9963D526" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.4" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Tk DLL" COMPANY_NAME="ActiveState Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Tk 8.6 for Windows" FILE_VERSION="8.6.4" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="tk86.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2001 by ActiveState Corporation, et al" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x162A03" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 23:31:57" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 23:31:57" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="wish.exe" SIZE="393216" CHECKSUM="0x4A8216DD" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.4" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Wish Application" COMPANY_NAME="ActiveState Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Tk 8.6 for Windows" FILE_VERSION="8.6.4" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="wish86.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2000 by ActiveState Corporation, et al" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 23:31:58" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 23:31:58" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="wish86.exe" SIZE="393216" CHECKSUM="0x4A8216DD" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.4" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Wish Application" COMPANY_NAME="ActiveState Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Tk 8.6 for Windows" FILE_VERSION="8.6.4" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="wish86.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2000 by ActiveState Corporation, et al" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x1" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 23:31:58" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 23:31:58" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="zlib1.dll" SIZE="107520" CHECKSUM="0x6E91C07D" BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.2.8.0" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.2.8.0" PRODUCT_VERSION="1.2.8" FILE_DESCRIPTION="zlib data compression library" PRODUCT_NAME="zlib" FILE_VERSION="1.2.8" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="zlib1.dll" INTERNAL_NAME="zlib1.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="(C) 1995-2013 Jean-loup Gailly &amp; Mark Adler" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x20A00" LINKER_VERSION="0x10000" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="1.2.8.0" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="1.2.8.0" LINK_DATE="05/13/2013 12:42:08" UPTO_LINK_DATE="05/13/2013 12:42:08" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="FOLDER\freewrap.exe" SIZE="8674276" CHECKSUM="0x87EABBB8" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x347472" LINKER_VERSION="0x10000" LINK_DATE="02/22/1970 08:06:24" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/22/1970 08:06:24" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="FOLDER\freewrap664\win32\freewrap.exe" SIZE="8674276" CHECKSUM="0x87EABBB8" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x347472" LINKER_VERSION="0x10000" LINK_DATE="02/22/1970 08:06:24" UPTO_LINK_DATE="02/22/1970 08:06:24" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="FOLDER\freewrap664\win32\freewrapTCLSH.exe" SIZE="5935627" CHECKSUM="0x4728114A" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1E8C2F" LINKER_VERSION="0x10000" LINK_DATE="07/04/1971 17:12:48" UPTO_LINK_DATE="07/04/1971 17:12:48" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="FOLDER\freewrap664\win64\freewrap.exe" SIZE="9044047" CHECKSUM="0xEAAC5906" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x3406BC" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="01/19/2015 01:41:48" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/19/2015 01:41:48" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="FOLDER\freewrap664\win64\freewrapTCLSH.exe" SIZE="6025630" CHECKSUM="0xD1018E6A" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x1D252E" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" LINK_DATE="01/15/2015 01:21:20" UPTO_LINK_DATE="01/15/2015 01:21:20" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="FOLDER\kit\tclkit.exe" SIZE="1334267" CHECKSUM="0xEFE507F5" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.5.2.9" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.5.2.9" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.5.9" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Tclkit, a standalone runtime for Tcl/Tk" COMPANY_NAME="Equi4 Software" PRODUCT_NAME="Tclkit 8.5 for Windows" FILE_VERSION="8.5.9" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="tclkit-gui.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 1989-2009 by J.Ousterhout et al." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.5.2.9" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.5.2.9" LINK_DATE="09/09/2010 09:22:14" UPTO_LINK_DATE="09/09/2010 09:22:14" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="FOLDER\kit\tclkit2.exe" SIZE="1334267" CHECKSUM="0xEFE507F5" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.5.2.9" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.5.2.9" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.5.9" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Tclkit, a standalone runtime for Tcl/Tk" COMPANY_NAME="Equi4 Software" PRODUCT_NAME="Tclkit 8.5 for Windows" FILE_VERSION="8.5.9" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="tclkit-gui.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 1989-2009 by J.Ousterhout et al." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.5.2.9" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.5.2.9" LINK_DATE="09/09/2010 09:22:14" UPTO_LINK_DATE="09/09/2010 09:22:14" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="FOLDER\kit\tclkit864.exe" SIZE="3933431" CHECKSUM="0x717476F1" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.4" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Tclkit, a standalone runtime for Tcl/Tk" COMPANY_NAME="Equi4 Software" PRODUCT_NAME="Tclkit 8.6 for Windows" FILE_VERSION="8.6.4" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="tclkit-gui.exe" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 1989-2009 by J.Ousterhout et al." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x0" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" LINK_DATE="04/12/2015 23:13:37" UPTO_LINK_DATE="04/12/2015 23:13:37" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="tcl86.dll" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="tcl86.dll" SIZE="1228800" CHECKSUM="0x3BC33EBF" BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.4" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Tcl DLL" COMPANY_NAME="ActiveState Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Tcl 8.6 for Windows" FILE_VERSION="8.6.4" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="tcl86.dll" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="Copyright © 2001 by ActiveState Corporation, et al" VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x4" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x12F33A" LINKER_VERSION="0x0" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="8.6.2.4" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.6.2.4" LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 22:59:49" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/12/2015 22:59:49" VER_LANGUAGE="Englisch (USA) [0x409]" />
</EXE>
<EXE NAME="kernel32.dll" FILTER="GRABMI_FILTER_THISFILEONLY">
    <MATCHING_FILE NAME="kernel32.dll" SIZE="1067008" CHECKSUM="0xD3859AE" BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.6532" BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.6532" PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.6532" FILE_DESCRIPTION="Client-DLL für Windows NT-Basis-API" COMPANY_NAME="Microsoft Corporation" PRODUCT_NAME="Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®" FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.6532 (xpsp_sp3_qfe.140312-0419)" ORIGINAL_FILENAME="kernel32" INTERNAL_NAME="kernel32" LEGAL_COPYRIGHT="© Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten." VERFILEDATEHI="0x0" VERFILEDATELO="0x0" VERFILEOS="0x40004" VERFILETYPE="0x2" MODULE_TYPE="WIN32" PE_CHECKSUM="0x10EBEB" LINKER_VERSION="0x50001" UPTO_BIN_FILE_VERSION="5.1.2600.6532" UPTO_BIN_PRODUCT_VERSION="5.1.2600.6532" LINK_DATE="03/12/2014 10:48:40" UPTO_LINK_DATE="03/12/2014 10:48:40" VER_LANGUAGE="Deutsch (Deutschland) [0x407]" />
</EXE>
</DATABASE>
```

Yes, I'm using Windows for this. Can't use Linux for this task due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405054/linux-telnet-vt100-return-key-sends-m).
How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do some of it fairly easily by using a few more features of Expect. In particular, the `expect` command can wait for a regular expression to be matched and report what substrings match, and then use `string index` to pick the characters out of the secret.

```
expect -re {Login \[(\d)(\d)(\d)\]:}
# It's wise to copy these values from expect_out into other variables immediately
set digitA $expect_out(1,string)
set digitB $expect_out(2,string)
set digitC $expect_out(3,string)

# Is it zero-based or one-based indexing? Assuming the latter...
set charA [string index $secret [expr {$digitA - 1}]]
set charB [string index $secret [expr {$digitB - 1}]]
set charC [string index $secret [expr {$digitC - 1}]]
```

I'm not quite sure how you assemble those letters into the response — your description wasn't clear enough — but I'm sure you can figure that out now that you've got the raw materials.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My TCL is struggling with the first line you provided (`expect -re {Login \[(\d)(\d)(\d)\]:}`). This line causes TCL to crash. If I change the expect parameter syntax to `expect {-re -n "Login \[(\d)(\d)(\d)\]:"}`, TCL does'nt crash but exits before `Login [517]:
XYZ SMC via AB1CDE-11 >` is being received. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Btw one-based indexing is used. The solution you provided applies logical to my case.